# Many-to-many relation return empty result

Tags: sql-server

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[studies_profile]
(
    [std_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [course_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [term_id] [int] NOT NULL
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[student] 
(
    std_id int primary key not null,
    std_fname nvarchar(50) null,
    std_lname nvarchar(50) not null,
    std_mail nvarchar(100),
    std_birthdate datetime
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[course]
(
     course_id int primary key NOT NULL,
     course_code int NOT NULL,
     course_name nvarchar(15) NOT NULL,
     course_program_code int NOT NULL,
) 
GO

/* --------------------------------- */

ALTER TABLE studies_profile  
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_course_studies_profile
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course(course_id) 
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE studies_profile 
    ADD CONSTRAINT FK_student_studies_profile 
    FOREIGN KEY (std_id) REFERENCES student(std_id)  
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

INSERT INTO student 
VALUES (1, 'aaa', 'g', '1@gmail.com', '2000-1-17'),
       (2, 'bbb', 's', '2@gmail.com', '1999-2-17'),
       (3, 'ccc', 'k', '3@gmail.com', '1995-3-17'),
       (4, 'ddd', 'm', '4@gmail.com', '1998-4-17');

INSERT INTO course 
VALUES (1, 1111, 'math', 1), (2, 1111, 'cpp', 1),
       (3, 3333, 'mat', 2), (4, 4444, 'c++', 4),
       (5, 5555, 'en', 5), (6, 6666, 'fr', 6);
```

When I run the following query, I get nothing returned, it is many to many relation as I know.

What I need is to know the name of student with course_name aaa

```
select 
    student.std_fname, student.std_lname,
    course.course_id, course.course_name
from  
    student
left join 
    studies_profile on (student.std_id = studies_profile.std_id)
left join 
    course on (studies_profile.course_id = course.course_id)
where 
    course.course_name = 'aaa'
```

Comment: This sure looks like sql server code and not mysql.

Comment: There is no course name = "aaa", how could there be a student with such a course. You have a _student_ with that name though.

Comment: You shouldn't use `LEFT JOIN` if you only want rows that match a condition on the second table, you should use `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: sorry miss writing, it is 'math', by example

Comment: i have tried inner join by nothing happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection table `dbo.studies_profile` is blank (i.e., the OP does not contain inserts to this table), therefor no results will come back. You need to populate it with the mapping data. Once that is done, then you will receive results. Though, as @Uueerdo correctly pointed out, there is no 'aaa' course, so you still won't receive a result. You will also need to correct your query constraint.

Note: SQL Server does not figure out mapping for you because it has no way of knowing what the mapping is. I'm not sure if that was your intent, but if it was then it won't work.